# Enable/disable UIButton according to number of characters in UITextField in ReactiveCocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I want to set the `enabled` property of a `UIButton` to `true` iff there is at least one character in a `UITextField`. How can this be achieved in [Reactive Cocoa 4](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
  .rac_notifications(UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: textField)
   .map { $0.object as! UITextField }
   .map { $0.text }
   .map { $0.isEmpty }
   .startWithNext { button.enabled = !$0 }
```